# Subtotal <> sum of the rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I'm a relative neophyte with DAX so bear with me.  In the simplest terms, I want to double the measure amount for all regions that are not Europe, then sum the result.  Here is some example DAX:

```
DEFINE
    
measure Fact[test] = CALCULATE (IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Dim'[Region]) = "Europe", Fact[Revenue],Fact[Revenue] * 2))

EVALUATE(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL('Dim'[Region], "RegionSubtotal"),
        "Original Measure", Fact[Revenue],
        "New Measure", Fact[test]
    )
)
```

| Region | RegionSubtotal | Original Measure | New Measure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asia | False | 200 | 400 |
| Americas | False | 500 | 1000 |
| Europe | False | 300 | 300 |
|  | True | 1000 | **2000** |

I'm trying to get (400+1000+300) = 1700 for the second column instead of 2000.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the subtotal row, the selected value is not "Europe" so it's doubling the value.

To fix this, you want to iterate over the regions in your measure. Something like this:

```
test =
    SUMX (
        VALUES ( 'Dim'[Region] ),
        IF (
            'Dim'[Region] = "Europe",
            [Revenue],
            [Revenue] * 2
        )
    )
```

Comment: That does make sense (evaluate each row individually and sum the result) but unfortunately i'm getting the same result as before

Comment: I think the SELECTEDVALUE should be removed, since inside the SUMX we have a row context over 'Dim'[Region]

Comment: Thanks, looks like that did it.

Comment: Please can you tell me what is the purpose of using VALUES instead of the table name (without VALIES).

Comment: If there is only one row per `Region` then the table name works fine. I used VALUES in case `'Dim'` has more than one row per `Region`, which would make the calculation less efficient (since it's iterating over more rows) and prone to double-counting in some cases (e.g. if `[Revenue]` modifies the filter context in certain ways).

Answer (score 1):

An other alternative would be to create a calculated column wherein , in case if region<>Europe, then amount* 2 else amount.
Then take the sum of the calculated column , but this would be like having an additional data .