# Subtotal not reflecting sum of underlying row calculations

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

This is kind of similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515750/subtotal-sum-of-the-rows), but different enough i think to justify a new question.  Looking at the below table, i want to take the total of Direct Expense across all regions, and subtract that from the Americas Expense number only, then total up the result.

[image]

I'd like the last column's total to read 17,661, not 54,888.  Here is a link to a sample workbook on OneDrive with the above table:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al7VQqB8RVlWgY4mUYqouesRPNE0qw?e=IiMPnq   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your measure had two issues:

1. it was missing the context transition, this can be fixed adding
   `CALCULATE` where a context transition is needed
2. The `[Total Direct Expense total for Region  (c)]` uses `ALLSELECTED`,
   ad it's called inside an iterator. But we can move the measure
   before the iteration using a variable instead. (The number 13,703 is wrong)

The measure then becomes

```
Final Result (a-c) = 
VAR TotalExpense = [Total Direct Expense total for Region  (c)]
RETURN
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Sheet1[Region] ),
    IF (
        Sheet1[Region] = "Americas",
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Sheet1[Total Expense (a)] ) - TotalExpense
        ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Sheet1[Total Expense (a)] )
        )
    )
)
```

Now the final result is

[image: final resulting table visual]

A rather complex article about ALLSELECTED explaining what is the shadow filter and why calling ALLSELECTED after a context transition in an iteration doesn't work as expcected can be found here https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-allselected/

Comment: Great, thanks.  it's confusing why creating the variable makes a difference because there is no logic being added; it seems just by being within a variable the ALLSELECTED behaves differently.  i will check out the article.

Comment: Yes, the key is that ALLSELECTED works by restoring the last saved "shadow filter". In our case this becomes VALUES( Sheet1[Region] ), that is the first argument of SUMX. The article explains it in detail. In our case, usina a variable we make ALLSELECTED work before the shadow filter is changed by SUMX.