# function Or In If statement DAX

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I currently have some columns in a power Query Table:

`Client Quantity` &  `Quantity Delivered`.

I want to have a table which count "1" When `Client Quantity` are equal to `Quantity Delivered` and 0 in the contrary.

I tried this:

```
 [`Client Quantity`]=`Quantity delivered`],
    1,
        0
    )
```

Which works, but some `Client Quantity` and `Quantity delivered` are empty and power bi counts it like a 0.

I only want to keep real data

I tried this:

```
    Livraisons blanches = 
 IF(
         [Client Quantity]=[Quantity Delivered]
                    1,
                    IF(
                        [Client Quantity]= BLANK(),
                        BLANK,
                            IF(
                                [Quantity Delivered]=BLANK(),
                                BLANK(),
                                2
                            )
                    )
 )
```

But it's not currently working.

Can I regroup both `Client Quantity` and `Client Delivered` to exclude them from the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
Livraisons blanches =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( [Client Quantity] ) || ISBLANK ( [Quantity Delivered] ),
    BLANK (),
    IF ( [Client Quantity] = [Quantity Delivered], 1, 0 )
)
```

Comment: Thank you by a lot its working

By any chance do you know why the counter isnt working? It stay at 0 despite multiples "1"

Comment: I don't know what "counter" you're referring to.

Comment: the total in table bottom (the sum currently)

Comment: The table total isn't summing up the individual rows but rather calculating the measure just like each of the individual rows does. Since there's a quantity mismatch, it returns 0.

Comment: Ok thank for the answer, is there a way to calculate the total?

Comment: Yes, but that's a separate question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515750) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953022) for similar questions.

Comment: I will look into it and post a separate question if i don't find any result.